# VBScript - Running Macro within script for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have searched this community and others and I'm still having difficulties getting this to work.

I would like to have a VB Script that when I execute it will open an Excel document, run a script (macro), and close excel.

The macro doesn't exist in the document I am opening, that's why I would like to have the macro in the VB script

I have tried to modify this, but with no luck. When I enter my macro code into this it fails. I understand that VBS and VBA are different but I am not very experienced with either.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\scripts\test.xls")
       Set xlmodule = objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1) 
       strCode = _
       "sub test()" & vbCr & _
       "   msgbox ""Inside the macro"" " & vbCr & _
       "end sub"
       xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode
objWorkbook.SaveAs "c:\scripts\test.xls"
objExcel.Quit
```

This is the macro I am trying to merge into this VB script.

```
Sub Billing_Cleanup()

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Rows("1:8").Select
    Range("A8").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ChDir "C:\Billing Export"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what does NOT work at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't just guess what is not working for you but merging/*replacing* the macro should be straight forward...

Replace your current code in the VBScript file with the below, save and run see if this is what you want

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\scripts\test.xls")
       Set xlmodule = objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1) 
       strCode = _
        "Sub Billing_Cleanup()" & vbCr & _
        "    Columns(""A:A"").Select" & vbCr & _
        "    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft" & vbCr & _
        "    Rows(""1:8"").Select" & vbCr & _
        "    Range(""A8"").Activate" & vbCr & _
        "    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp" & vbCr & _
        "    Columns(""E:E"").Select" & vbCr & _
        "    Selection.ClearContents" & vbCr & _
        "    ChDir ""C:\Billing Export""" & vbCr & _
        "    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True, CreateBackup:=False" & vbCr & _
        "    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized" & vbCr & _
        "    Application.WindowState = xlNormal" & vbCr & _
        "    Application.DisplayAlerts = False" & vbCr & _
        "    ActiveWorkbook.Close" & vbCr & _
        "    Application.Quit" & vbCr & _
        "End Sub"
       xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode

objExcel.Application.Run "test.xls!Billing_Cleanup"  
objWorkbook.Save
objExcel.Quit
```

Note an extra `"` double quote to escape quotes inside a String

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. I was getting a syntax error on Line 7 char 1. This has been resolved by mehow by writing out the macro correctly. I am now getting a Unknown runtime error on Line 25 char 1. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @user3087335 can you run the macro in your workbook without using VBScript file and verify that the embed macro itself runs correctly?

Comment: @user3087335 I can't see line numbers, which line is giving you an error? and what is the error message?

Comment: Error: Unknow runtime error
Code: 800A9C68

Line:25 Char:1

Which is this: objExcel.Application.Run "test.xls!Billing_Cleanup"  

Please note: Despite getting this error the macro is working within this VB script because the file is being exported correctly.

Comment: I figured it out. The macro told excel to close before the VB script was done. I removed that out of the Marco and it works without error! Thank you!